# How do I hide a div if there are no visible children in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, visibility

I'm trying to hide a parent div if the child items are all invisible. I can hide the parent if there are no children but cannot determine how to hide based on visibility;

```
<div ng-repeat="group in section.groups" ng-show="group.fields.length > 0">
 <input  ng-if='field.isVisible' type="text" name="{{ field.id }}" id="{{ field.id }}" ng-model="field.value" /> 
</div>
```

Can someone please provide an example of how to show the outer div only when there are inputs that meet the ng-if condition of field.isVisible?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: can  you not just use JS/Jquery to determine if the children are visible or not and then set the visibility of the div?

Comment: Also if all the children are invisible what is the point of hiding the parent div, if I may ask?

Comment: You could simply set `width:auto;height:auto;` in CSS? Or simply skip `width` and `height` rules.

Comment: If I used CSS or inline styles the elements would still be rendered on the DOM. My requirement was such that the elements should not exist at all unless the children were present in the Angular model data.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, no sooner had I posted the question than I realised I could filter based on a property then check the length as follows;

```
<div ng-repeat="group in section.groups" ng-show="(group.fields | filter:{isVisible:true}).length > 0">
 <input  ng-if='field.isVisible' type="text" name="{{ field.id }}" id="{{ field.id }}" ng-model="field.value" /> 
</div>
```